# amazon web services instance id .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services

I am starting to use AWS toolkit for .NET, using C# as programming language. I would like to know if there's any chance to get instance ids using .NET AWS toolkit, so you don't have to specify the instance id as a parameter. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using the method:

```
EC2InstanceMetadata.GetData(EC2InstanceMetadata.InstanceId)
```